# Select statement to show the corresponding user with the lowest/highest amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write a select statement output that, among other things, has both a lowest_bid and highest_bid column. I know how to do that bit, but want I also want is to show the user (user_firstname and user_lastname combined into their own column) as lowest_bidder and highest_bidder. What I have so far is:

```
select item_name, item_reserve, count(bid_id) as number_of_bids, 
       min(bid_amount) as lowest_bid, ???, max(big_amount) as highest_bid,
       ???
       from vb_items
       join vb_bids on item_id=bid_item_id
       join vb_users on item_seller_user_id=user_id
       where bid_status =  ‘ok’ and
          item_sold = ‘no’
       sort by item_reserve
```

(The ???'s are where the columns should go, once I figure out what to put there!)

Comment: instead of `item_seller_user_id` is there a column on bids for the bidding `user_id`?

Comment: There's an item_buyer_user_id.

Comment: How can you tell who made the lowest bid if there's no link between bid and user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like good use of window functions. I've assumed a column `vb_bids.bid_user_id`. If there's no link between a bid and a user, you can't answer this question

```
With x as (
    Select
        b.bid_item_id,
        count(*) over (partition by b.bid_item_id) as number_of_bids,
        row_number() over (
            partition by b.bid_item_id 
            order by b.bid_amount desc
        ) as high_row,
        row_number() over (
            partition by b.bid_item_id 
            order by b.bid_amount
        ) as low_row,
        b.bid_amount,
        u.user_firstname + ' ' + u.user_lastname username
    From
        vb_bids b
            inner join
        vb_users u
            on b.bid_user_id = u.user_id
    Where
        b.bid_status = 'ok'
)
Select
    i.item_name,
    i.item_reserve,
    min(x.number_of_bids) number_of_bids,
    min(case when x.low_row = 1 then x.bid_amount end) lowest_bid,
    min(case when x.low_row = 1 then x.username end) low_bidder,
    min(case when x.high_row = 1 then x.bid_amount end) highest_bid,
    min(case when x.high_row = 1 then x.username end) high_bidder 
From
    vb_items i
        inner join
    x
        on i.item_id = x.bid_item_id
Where
    i.item_sold = 'no'
Group By
    i.item_name,
    i.item_reserve
Order By
    i.item_reserve
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db0c/10)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the users, I broke out the aggregates into their own tables, joined them by the `item_id` and filtered them by a derived value that is either the min or max of `bid_amount`.  I could have joined to `vb_bids` for a third time, and kept the aggregate functions, but that would've been redundant.

This will fail if you have two low bids of the exact same amount for the same item, since the join is on `bid_amount`.  If you use this, then you'd want to created an index on `vb_bids` covering `bid_amount`.

```
select item_name, item_reserve, count(bid_id) as number_of_bids, 
   low_bid.bid_amount as lowest_bid, low_user.first_name + ' ' + low_user.last_name, 
   high_bid.bid_amount as highest_bid, high_user.first_name + ' ' + high_user.last_name
   from vb_items
   join vb_bids AS low_bid on item_id = low_bid.bid_item_id
      AND low_bid.bid_amount = (
         SELECT MIN(bid_amount) 
         FROM vb_bids 
         WHERE bid_item_id = low_bid.bid_item_id)
   join vb_bids AS high_bid on item_id = high_bid.bid_item_id
      AND high_bid.bid_amount = (
         SELECT MAX(bid_amount) 
         FROM vb_bids 
         WHERE bid_item_id = high_bid.bid_item_id)
   join vb_users AS low_user on low_bid.user_id=user_id
   join vb_users AS high_user on high_bid.user_id=user_id
   where bid_status =  ‘ok’ and
      item_sold = ‘no’
   group by item_name, item_reserve, 
   low_bid.bid_amount, low_user.first_name, low_user.last_name, 
   high_bid.bid_amount, high_user.first_name, high_user.last_name
   order by item_reserve
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) for situations like this, because of the following advantages:

- Separating different parts of the logic, adding to readability, and
- Reducing complexity (for example, the need to GROUP BY a large number of fields, or to repeat the same join multiple times.)

So, my suggested approach would be something like this:

```
-- semi-colon must precede CTE
;

-- collect bid info  
WITH item_bids AS (
  SELECT 
    i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_reserve, b.bid_id, b.bid_amount, 
    (u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name) AS bid_user_name
  FROM vb_items i
    JOIN vb_bids b ON i.item_id = b.bid_item_id
    JOIN vb_users u ON b.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE b.bid_status = 'ok'
    AND i.item_sold = 'no'
), 

-- group bid info
item_bid_info AS ( 
  SELECT item_id, item_name, item_reserve
    COUNT(bid_id) AS number_of_bids, MIN(bid_amount) AS lowest_bid, MAX(bid_amount) AS highest_bid
  FROM item_bids
  GROUP BY item_id, item_name, item_reserve
)

-- assemble final result
SELECT 
  bi.item_name, bi.item_reserve, bi.number_of_bids, 
  bi.low_bid,  low_bid.bid_user_name AS low_bid_user, 
  bi.high_bid, high_bid.bid_user_name AS high_bid_user
FROM item_bid_info bi
  JOIN item_bids AS low_bid  ON bi.lowest_bid = low_bid.bid_amount  AND bi.item_id = low_bid.bid_item_id
  JOIN item_bids AS high_bid ON bi.lowest_bid = high_bid.bid_amount AND bi.item_id = high_bid.bid_item_id
ORDER BY bi.item_reserve;
```

Note that the entire SQL statement (from the starting `WITH` all the way down to the final semi-colon after the `ORDER BY`) is a single statement, and is evaluated by the optimizer as such. (Some people think each part is evaluated separately, like temp tables, and then all the rows are joined together at the end in a final step. That's not how it works. CTEs are just as efficient as sub-queries.)

Also note that this approach does a `JOIN` on the bid amount, so if there are identical bids for a single item, it will fail. (Seems like that should be an invalid state anyway, though, right?) Also you may have efficiency concerns depending on:

- The size of your table
- Whether the lookup can use an index

You could address both issues by including a unique constraint (which has the added advantage of indexing the foreign key bid_item_id as well; always a good practice):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[vb_bids] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_vbBids_item_amount] 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (bid_item_id, bid_amount)
GO
```

Hope that helps!